# Calculate a row number for every distinct occurrence of

Tags: mysql

I am trying to number specific values within a column. You can see I've already sorted the table based upon date, it is important for the query to number based upon the already sorted date (from lowest value based on date to highest value.)

I seeking to assign a number to the visits it takes for a potential customer to become a customer.

```
Ad Group|Vist Date |Phone Number
--------+----------+------------
A.      |09/01/2018|555-444-3321
A.      |09/02/2018|777-454-3333
A.      |09/03/2018|555-444-3321
A.      |09/04/2018|777-454-3333
A.      |09/05/2018|555-444-3321
A.      |09/06/2018|777-454-3333
A.      |09/07/2018|555-444-3321
A.      |09/08/2017|777-454-3333

Desired Output


Ad Group|Visit Date|Phone Number|Number of Occurrences within date
--------+----------+------------+---------------------------------
A.      |09/01/2018|555-444-3321|1
A.      |09/02/2018|777-454-3333|1
A.      |09/03/2018|555-444-3321|2 
A.      |09/04/2018|777-454-3333|2
A.      |09/05/2018|555-444-3321|3
A.      |09/05/2017|888-465-9999|1
A.      |09/06/2018|777-454-3333|3
A.      |09/07/2018|555-444-3321|4
A.      |09/08/2017|777-454-3333|4
A.      |09/08/2017|999-432-1111|1
A.      |09/09/2017|888-465-9999|2
```

Comment: What MySQL version? execute `SELECT VERSION()`

Comment: if latest version of mysql `Row_number() over (partition by Ad_Group, phone_Number order by visit_Date asc)` as NoOfOccurWithinDate  otherwise you have to use case logic and user variables and simulate the analytic function http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/ https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html 8.0+

Comment: So if Ad Group `B.` existed....  would the #'s start over for the same phone number?

Answer (score 1):

Query that should create Your desired output:

```
SELECT t1.ad_group
     , t1.visit_date
     , t1.phone_number
     , (SELECT count(*) 
        FROM tbl_table t2 
        WHERE t1.phone_number=t2.phone_number 
          AND t2.visit_date<=t1.visit_date) as number_of_occuvences_within_date 
FROM tbl_table t1 
ORDER BY t1.visit_date
```

Comment: Creative solution.  I think you need to have the correlation include the ad_group as well for it to be more accurate.  The only aspect I don't like about it is the subquery gets executed for EVERY record meaning thousands of queries could be executed to get the final results  So on a LARGE dataset this could be slow.

Comment: @xQbert it is a correlated subquery. It will be fast enough. Solution is really nice and simple. I didn't check it seriously, until you edited it for readability

Answer (score 1):

Following solution shall work for all the MySQL versions (**especially < 8.0)**:

- Using session variables, calculate number of occurrences for every phone number, in increasing order of date. It is similar to [emulating row_number() functionality](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/).
- Now, use this result-set as a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), and order by date again.

Try the following query (please change table and column name(s) accordingly):

```
SET @num_occurence = 0;
SET @phone_no = '';

SELECT derived_t.ad_group, 
       derived_t.visit_date, 
       derived_t.phone_number, 
       derived_t.number_of_occurences 
FROM 
(
  SELECT t1.ad_group, 
         t1.visit_date, 
         @num_occurence := CASE
                             WHEN @phone_no = t1.phone_number
                               THEN @num_occurence + 1
                             ELSE 1
                           END AS number_of_occurences, 
         @phone_no := t1.phone_number AS phone_number 
  FROM your_table AS t1 
  ORDER BY t1.phone_number ASC, t1.visit_date ASC 
) AS derived_t 
ORDER BY derived_t.visit_date ASC
```

Comment: Little risk of needing to partition by the ad group as well. but that wasn't well defined in the question.

Comment: @xQbert yep, but question has only one ad group

Answer (score 1):

If you're using 8.0 + then... window functions are available and this is pretty straight forward.

```
SELECT `Ad Group`
     , `Visit Date`
     , `Phone Number`
     , ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY `Ad Group`, `Phone Number` ORDER BY Visit Date Asc) as `Number of Occurrences within date`
FROM TableName
ORDER BY `Visit Date` asc
```

The window function simply considers `ag group` and `phone numbers` as a "Unique key" and orders this key by visit date asc and then assigns the numbers 1-x for each row encountered of the unique key (1 for each date).  If dates are duplicated for a given group and number, we don't have a specific order defined and the records will be assigned the next two numbers for that unique key.  If we use Dense_Rank() window function instead each row would be assigned the same number.

The window function allows the sort and numbering to occur interdependently of the order by and the select.  This allows us to assign the rows for each "partition" of data (ad group and phone number) ordered by the visit date.  Thus allowing the #'s to start at 1 for each partition and increment by 1 for each date row encountered; in the order of the visit dates ascending.

If it's not 8.0+ then ignore this post ;P

Some Window functions include:

- Row_Number()
- Rank()
- Dense_Rank()
- Sum()
- Count()
- Lead()
- Lag()

Docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that I have correctly understood your question, the following query should help:

```
SELECT `Ad Group`, `Visit Date`, `Phone Number`, count(*) `Number of Occurrences within date`
FROM <table name>
ORDER BY `Visit Date` (ASC|DESC)
GROUP BY `Phone Number`
```

In theory the above query should always return the first row of each group.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question correctly.  the desired output shows all the rows with a row number not just the first row of each group.